# Secure Gateway cannot be bound to Bluemix app

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

When trying to binding any Bluemix apps to a pre-configured Secure Gateway service, the Secure Gateway is not in the list of services which can be bound to apps. Is there a different way to bind a nodejs app to a Secure Gateway instance?

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to managed the SG or just connect through it? It should be transparent.

Comment: It used to be a requirement to bind the secure gateway to apps wanting to tunnel through it, so I assumed that was still the case?

Comment: Not needed. You need the URI for the service you want to access, e.g. a JDBC URL. Depending on what you want to do. Here is an old blog on that: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/11/twelve-factor-app-avoid-configuration-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

Applications can no longer be bound to the Secure Gateway service.  Binding was possible in previous versions but provided no additional functionality to the application.

To have your application use the connectivity provided by Secure Gateway, your application simply needs to call the cloud host:port provided by your destination.